# How to install Vim with custom compile options using the Nix package manager?

Tags: vim, nix, nixos

I only needed Vim with `+clipboard` and was able to figure it out (see below), but adding compile options to Vim is not documented (or at least I didn't see it in the Nixpkgs manual section [9.17. User’s Guide to Vim Plugins/Addons/Bundles/Scripts in Nixpkgs](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#users-guide-to-vim-pluginsaddonsbundlesscripts-in-nixpkgs)) and the default Vim package is not compiled with the most popular options (see [issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/26726)).

My solution was to install Vim with the HUGE feature set (also not documented anywhere, but found it in one of the resources below):

```
nix-env -iA nixpkgs.vimHugeX
```

[`vimHugeX` is an alias to `vim_configurable`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/b3af2cd9627d717820c96259a878f24687066cf1/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix#L18682). It seems that [`vim_configurable`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/applications/editors/vim/configurable.nix) is the key based on these resources:

- [[Nix-dev] Configuring vim with override](https://nixos.org/nix-dev/2016-March/019864.html)
- [[Nix-dev] How do I change vim compile options from my configuration.nix?](https://nixos.org/nix-dev/2015-November/018754.html)
- [Use Nix to build vim with +python support + custom python libraries](https://gist.github.com/aaronlevin/9a933624d3fda83b01b06acb2aeea0a6)

Comment: I haven't used Nix package manager, but personally I found Valloric's (the maintainer of the YouCompleteMe plugin) guide to building vim from source to be the most useful resource when trying to customise which options you want compiled.

https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source

Comment: Thanks! I have been using this same post as a reference actually, but I was specifically interested in how to configure a custom Vim installation with Nix.

Comment: Have you tried writing a [nix expression](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#chap-writing-nix-expressions)?  If so, what do you have so far?

Comment: @sk8forether Being strapped for time I just went with the `nixpkgs.vimHugeX` solution. Love Nix, but serious time needs to be invested in it to learn it properly (for me, at least), and the Github nixpkgs already seems untenable. [Domen Kožar](https://twitter.com/domenkozar/)'s [Cachix](https://cachix.org/) seems to be the best alternative, and once I get to spend diving into Nix again, I'll add an answer here. I wish there was a comprehensive resource for Nix and its ecosystem.